# In Kotlin, How can I pass function that uses generic as a arguments to some class?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to pass a function type that has generic as a arguments to a class but I don't know how to make it.

```
class Remote constructor(
    val executor: (call: Call<T>) -> T
)
```

With above example, The compiler complains T is unresolved.

I DON'T want to add generic `T` to `Remote` class like `Remote<T>`.

Is there any way to pass `val executor: (call: Call<T>) -> T` to the class `Remote` ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-assign-generic-function-to-variable/16419/6 Spoiler: It's not possible

Comment: Why don't you create a generic Executor class?

Comment: *I DON'T want to add generic T to Remote class like Remote<T>.* - but why? Do you want a different `T` for different calls to this `executor`? In that case, you could make `Remote` abstract, with an abstract paramterized `execute()` method

Answer (score 2):

If the `T` used by the provided `executor` is always the same for a given instance of `Remote`, then you should declare `T` on the `Remote` class.

Since you say you don't want to do that, I'm going to assume you expect different `T`s for different calls to `executor` on the same `Remote` instance.

In that case, you should probably declare `Remote` as abstract, with an abstract `execute` method taking a generic type parameter:

```kotlin
abstract class Remote {
    abstract fun <T> execute(call: Call<T>): T
}
```

Then instead of passing a lambda to `Remote`'s constructor, create an `object` that implements the method:

```kotlin
val remote = object : Remote {
    fun <T> execute(call: Call<T>): T {
        // do something that returns a T
    }
}
```

You can also create an explicit child class with a name instead of this anonymous object.